# Structure field overwritten when using memcpy

Tags: c, struct, memcpy, overwrite

I have the following struct and the code to fill it:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[CONTACT_NAME_SIZE];
    char surname[CONTACT_SURNAME_SIZE];
    char address[CONTACT_ADDRESS_SIZE];
    char phoneNumber[CONTACT_PHONENUMBER_SIZE];
} Contact;
```

...

```
char buffer[1024];
char phonebookItem[50];

printf("Name (max %d characters): ", CONTACT_NAME_SIZE);
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
memcpy(phonebookItem, buffer, sizeof(phonebookContacts[id].name));
strcpy(phonebookContacts[id].name, phonebookItem);

printf("Surname (max %d characters): ", CONTACT_SURNAME_SIZE);
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
memcpy(phonebookItem, buffer, sizeof(phonebookContacts[id].surname));
strcpy(phonebookContacts[id].surname, phonebookItem);

printf("Address (max %d characters): ", CONTACT_ADDRESS_SIZE);
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
memcpy(phonebookItem, buffer, sizeof(phonebookContacts[id].address));
strcpy(phonebookContacts[id].address, phonebookItem);

printf("Phone number (max %d characters): ", CONTACT_PHONENUMBER_SIZE);
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
memcpy(phonebookItem, buffer, sizeof(phonebookContacts[id].name));
strcpy(phonebookContacts[id].phoneNumber, phonebookItem);
```

The problem is that when I enter data for the first field, everything is OK. But when I enter data for the next field, everything I enter (both first and second input) is written into the first field and so on ...

Example:

```
Name (max 10 characters): 123456789*123456789
phonebookContacts[id].name = 123456789* -> OK
Surname (max 15 characters): 123456789*123456789*
phonebookContacts[id].name = 123456789*123456789*12345
phonebookContacts[id].surname = 123456789*12345
```

Why does it get overwritten?

Comment: Using `memcpy()` like this will cause undefined behavior if the user enters too much input, since your strings will be unterminated, but apart from that, it doesn't do what you claim. You've got some other error in your code, which could range from bad memory management to just trying to print these things out incorrectly. Not enough information to diagnose.

Comment: Why are you even using memcpy?

Comment: I am using memcpy because I have tried several methods to do what I want and only memcpy works (it "just" overwrite everything). I need to copy string from buffer to struct field, but I have to manage protection from too long strings.

Comment: ...and you 'manage protection from too long strings' wrong. `memcpy` wouldn't terminate your string if the are not terminated. Make sure you insert a zero byte (ASCII NUL character) at the last position of every overwritten buffer after overwriting it, e.g. `surname[CONTACT_SURNAME_SIZE - 1] = 0;`

Comment: You could always take the radical step of actually checking the length of the input *before* to try to copy it, and simply rejecting it if it's too long. This is probably better than silently truncating the input (how are you going to successful mail someone, if you rejected half their address?) even if the user did deliberately choose not to comply with the instructions.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of this:

```
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
memcpy(phonebookItem, buffer, sizeof(phonebookContacts[id].name));
strcpy(phonebookContacts[id].name, phonebookItem);
```

try this:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));  // zero out all of buffer
fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin); // accept up to n-1 input characters (last zero stays)
strncpy(phonebookContacts[id].name, buffer, CONTACT_NAME_SIZE-1);  // copy data
```

or:

```
memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));  // zero out all of buffer
fgets(buffer, CONTACT_NAME_SIZE, stdin); // accept up to field-specific number of  input characters
strcpy(phonebookContacts[id].name, buffer);  // copy data
```

assuming that the size of buffer is always greater than any input you may provide, and its size is also larger that any, or equal to the largest, of the fields you are inputting.

EDIT: added both options for clarity

Comment: Yep, I already tried this one before, but when I use size of field instead of size of buffer, stdin will overflow to another field, if it is bigger than maximu size I want. I use buffer to protect from too long input, but in your case if input is too long, I don't know how to take just first x characters from buffer and put it to struct field.

Comment: The function is: strncpy(to, from, number_of_chars), and it will stop if a zero byte is found in the 'from' string before it copies 'number_of_bytes'.  Also, you can use something like CONTACT_NAME_SIZE instead of sizeof(buffer), for example.

Comment: Using `sizeof(buffer)-1` with fgets() is not correct. fgets() will read up to size-1 bytes and then null terminate the buffer, so using full size is correct. It is actually strncpy() that requires size-1.

Comment: That was intentional, since it appears these sizes are arbitrary. This program cannot control what the user inputs. As for strncpy, it will simply stop at the number of bytes given and will not append a zero if one is not found at input, which makes the size-1 needed in both cases, just to end up with a maximum length zero-terminated string.

Comment: I'm not native English speaker, but after the edit, I hope my meaning is clear from the code :P